# Angular subscribed to an Observable but not refresh / update

Tags: angular, observable

I'm setting up a notifications feature to my Angular application.

**In header:**

The header is calling only one time after log-in, I have a badge with the number of unread notifications:

```
<button mat-icon-button>
    <mat-icon matBadge="{{unreadNotifications}}" matBadgeColor="red" matBadgeOverlap="true" matBadgePosition="below after">
        notifications
    </mat-icon>
</button>
```

And my controller:

```
notificationSub: Subscription;

ngOnInit() {
    this.notificationSub = this.notifService.getAsyncNotifsCount().subscribe((res) => {
        this.unreadNotifications = res;
    });
}
```

The notifications can be show in the **notification page**:

```
<div *ngFor="let notif of notifsBeforeRead" class="notif">
    <div class="notif-title">{{ notif.Subject }}</div>
    <div>{{ notif.Message }}</div>
    <div class="notif-date">{{ notif.Date | date : 'medium' }}</div>
</div>
```

And my controller:

```
notificationSub: Subscription;

this.notifService.apply({ collectionName: 'Links' }, myFilter);
this.notificationSub = this.notifService.getAsyncFilter()
  .subscribe((links) => {
    if (links.data && links.data.length) {
      // this.resultsLength = links.options.documents.total;
      this.resultsLength = 20;
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(links.data, (link) => {
        const notif = {};
        link.attributes.forEach((attr) => {
          notif['id'] = link._id;
          notif['attributes'] = link.attributes;
          link.attributes.forEach((att) => {
            notif[att.name] = att.value;
          });
        });
        if (Object.keys(notif).length) {
          notifications.push(notif);
        }
      });
    }
    this.notifsBeforeRead = notifications;
    this.notifications = _.cloneDeep(notifications);

  // Mark notifications as read
  this.updateReadNotif();
});
```

And my **notifService**:

```
@Injectable()
export class NotifService {
  filterSubject = new Subject<any>();
  notifsCountSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(0);

  apply(params = null, filter: any) {
    const _resource = this.resource;
    let targetURL = `${this.resourceApply}`;

    if (params) {
      targetURL += `?${queryParams(params)}`;
    }

    this.getData(targetURL, filter).subscribe((res) => {
      this.filterSubject.next(res);
      console.log(res.data);
      let unreadNotifs = 0;
      res.data.forEach((notif) => {
        notif.attributes.forEach((attr) => {
          if (attr.name === 'Lu' && attr.value === false) {
            unreadNotifs += 1;
          }
        });
      });
      this.notifsCountSubject.next(unreadNotifs);
    });
  }

  getData(targetURL, filter) {
    this.resource = targetURL;
    return from(super.create(filter));
  }

  getAsyncFilter() : Observable<any> {
    return this.filterSubject.asObservable();
  }

  getAsyncNotifsCount(): Observable<any> {
    return this.notifsCountSubject.asObservable();
  }
}
```

There isn't all the code but I guess you can help me with this only.

So when I go to the notifications page, the badge isn't updated.

**For example: I've got 5 unread notifs.**

- Badge in header = 5

I go notifications page so I pass in this code :

```
this.notifsCountSubject.next(unreadNotifs); // unreadNotifs = 0
```

But the badge in header isn't updated. I've subscribed to the subject, when I use .next(), all the subscribers should've update their data, am I right ?

Can you help me please, thanks you.

Comment: Do you use ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush anywhere?

Comment: @AmirArbabian Nope, should I ?

Comment: No, asked just in case

Comment: It's difficult to see the whole picture, but try to inject **cd: ChangeDetectorRef** into your header component and use **this.cd.markForCheck()** inside your **getAsyncNotifsCount().subscribe((res) => {**

Comment: It change nothing

Comment: So, are you sure that value in header component being updated and it's just not being rendered on html?

Comment: With console.log I'm seeing that when I pass in the service, the value of unreadNotif isn't correct, the problem come from my updateReadNotifications maybe, thanks for help I'll try to check where the problem come exactly and come back.

Comment: Ok, this is fixed but it still not refresh. I'm 100% sure the header component subject (notifsCountSubject) is updated with .next() in notifService, but the value in the header don't refresh / update, I don't know why. The code is the same (the code I had to edit isn't here)

Comment: After your value should be updated, try to "hover over"/"click" on that badge in header and check whether it's being updated or not

Comment: @AmirArbabian It doesn't update even if I click or hover over

Comment: Have you tried to add console.log(res); into getAsyncNotifsCount().subscribe((res) =>.. and check whether you can see new value in console?

Comment: @AmirArbabian Added screen, check edit

Comment: Ok, sorry i can't help you like that, i'm sure that i can figure out what was wrong, but i need at least sandbox where i can look on everything and so on. So if you want me to help you, could you please download part of your app on stackblitz where this bug reproduces, and i will solve it.

Comment: Otherwise, unfortunately, i won't be able to solve it.

Comment: It's a +3000 commits project, literally impossible to host like the project, when I try to reproduce with the minimum code it's working well XD. But I'm 100% sure my header component and my notifications component are using 2 differents notifsService instead one for both. Do you know / Have some tips for prevent this ? Edit, it's lazy loading + the header is calling only one time and is never "recall", even when switching page, maybe it can cause problem ?

Comment: Where you registered it, in module providers?

Comment: Ok, it should be registered **only once**, in one of the **root modules**, not features. + It **shouldn't be in providers in any component** check that

Comment: THANKSSSSS YOU SO MUCH !!!!! It was in a datatable providers :( ! You are the best!

Comment: No problem man, i'm glad that it helped you)

Comment: I will post short description in answer, so other users will see what was the problem, maybe it would help somebody someday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we figured out, the problem was that it was 2 different instances of service, because it was in providers of module and in providers of component, so component got new instance of service each time.